# How could I trick [CALayer renderInContext: ] to render only a section of the layer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, calayer

I'm well aware that there's no nice way to render a small part of a UIView to an image, besides rendering the whole view and cropping. (VERY expensive on something like an iPad 3, where the resulting image is huge). See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) for a description of the renderInContext method (there's no alternatives).

The part of the view that I want to render can't be predetermined, meaning I can't set up the view hierarchy for the small section to be it's own UIView (and therefore CALayer).

### My Idea...

I had an idea, but I need some direction if I'm going to succeed. What if I create a category on UIView (or CALayer) that adds a method along the lines of:

```
[UIView renderSubframe:(CGFrame)frame];
```

How? Well, I'm thinking that if a dummy view the size of the sub frame was created, then the view could be shifted temporarily onto this. Then the dummy view's layer could call renderInContext:, resulting in an efficient and fast way of getting views.

### So...

I'm really not that up to speed with CALayer/Quartz core stuff... Will this have any chance of working? If not, what's another way I could achieve the same thing - what's the most efficient way I could achieve the same result (or has anyone else already faced this problem and come up with a different solution)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's the category I ended up writing. Not as hard as I first thought, thanks to a handy CGAffineTransform.

```
#import "UIView+RenderSubframe.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIView (RenderSubframe)

- (UIImage *) renderWithBounds:(CGRect)frame {

    CGSize imageSize = frame.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextConcatCTM(c, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-frame.origin.x, -frame.origin.y));
    [self.layer renderInContext:c];

    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenshot;

}

@end
```

Comment: I've tested this and it appears that the drawRect called on the layer by the render operation is still drawing into the full size context.

Comment: @Plenilune testing using instruments shows a much lesser memory usage when this is called with a frame smaller than the view. In my case, the frame was screen sized, as opposed to view sized (which was 3x screen size).

Comment: I wanted to add that this category worked beautifully but there was a case where it wasn't rendering a UIImage animation that I had and it turns out that changing it to `[self.layer.presentationLayer renderInContext:c];` was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of different ways you might do this:

1. specify a `CGContextClipToRect` for your context before calling renderInContext;
2. use:

> setNeedsDisplayInRect:
>
> Marks the region within the specified rectangle as needing to be updated.
>
> ```
>      - (void)setNeedsDisplayInRect:(CGRect)theRect
> ```

This would make the rendering happen only in the specified rect. I am not sure though whether this would work as per your requirement.

I think that the first option should work seamlessly.

Comment: I may be wrong, but option 2 might result in a large image being produced (even though some of it may be blank)? A lot of the expensiveness of the renderInContext call seems to be the size of the image it creates, resulting in a very quick need for a lot of memory. Option 1 definitely has potential - will try this first!

Comment: Unfortunately CGContextClipToRect left the image as a large (mostly transparent) image, it only really worked when the frame origin was 0,0. You set me on the right track though, which resulted in me finding an easy solution!

Comment: care to share the solution, please?